# Cannot Change Width of TextView in Code

Tags: android, textview

What I want to do is that ... I want my `TextView` at the right side of the screen like "Note Edge" screen.

What I have tried is that

This is **XML**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MyActivity">

<TextView
    android:text="@string/hello_world"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:ellipsize="marquee"
    android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:id="@+id/txtVertical" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

This is **Java**

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);

    TextView txtVertical = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtVertical);
    txtVertical.setBackgroundColor(Color.CYAN);
    txtVertical.setPivotX(0);
    txtVertical.setPivotY(0);
    txtVertical.setRotation(90f);

    txtVertical.setX(100f);
    txtVertical.setY(100f);

    txtVertical.setText(txtVertical.getText() + "                                        ");
    txtVertical.setSelected(true);

    Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    Point size = new Point();
    display.getSize(size);

    //txtVertical.setWidth(size.y);              //doesn't work
    txtVertical.getLayoutParams().width = 1000;  //doesn't work also
    txtVertical.requestLayout();

    Log.d("size.y", size.y + "");

}
```

If I set the attribute `android:layout_width="wrap_content"`, it doesn't work either. How can I change the `width` of the `TextView`?

Answer (score 1):

**Try this :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtVertical"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:ellipsize="marquee"
        android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: @TunKyaw can you put screenshot of your `UI.` or put your layout (`.xml`) file

Comment: I cannot upload screen shot because I don't have enough reputation. Please check here http://i.stack.imgur.com/a0k2P.png (OR) 
https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=1470108816600542&set=a.1470108849933872.1073741827.100008043134995&type=1

Comment: @TunKyaw xml file plz.

Comment: There should be a library which is called VerticalTextView. You can try it.

Comment: txtVertical.setX(100f);
txtVertical.setY(100f);


Remove them and it will align to right.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this may helps you

```
    LayoutParams params = textView.getLayoutParams();
    params.height = 70;
    params.width= 50;
    textView.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try out;

> txtVertical.getLayoutParams().width = 200

(in pixel)

Comment: Can you please try to change width to fixed size from xml?

android:layout_width="100dp"

Comment: I cannot post screen shot because I don't have enough reputation. Please check here http://i.stack.imgur.com/a0k2P.png (OR) https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=1470108816600542&set=a.1470108849933872.1073741827.100008043134995&type=1

Comment: Can you add txtVertical.invalidate();

So we force textView to draw itself again.

Answer (score 0):

Just add these `layoutparams` to your `TextView` **programmatically**:

```
// Declaring the TextView LayoutParams
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams text_lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    text_lp.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;

// Declaring the TextView itself
    TextView txtVertical = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtVertical);
    txtVertical.setLayoutParams(text_lp);
    txtVertical.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);
    txtVertical.setSingleLine();
    txtVertical.setEllipsize(TruncateAt.MARQUEE);
    txtVertical.setSelected(true);
    //complete text your customization
```

Comment: `java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.LinearLayout$LayoutParams cannot be cast to android.widget.RelativeLayout$LayoutParams` error occurs!

Comment: yea change it to `RelativeLayout.LayoutParams` or just make it `LayoutParams`

Answer (score 0):

try this way

```
TextView txtVertical = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtVertical);
txtVertical.requestLayout();
txtVertical.getLayoutParams().height = 230;
txtVertical.getLayoutParams().width = 400;
txtVertical.setPadding(6, 6, 6, 6);
```